# ios UIWebView with youtube video

Tags: ios, youtube

I need to play the youtube videos in UIWebView and download the video files. And also need to get the notification for video play start and video play stop.

To do above things, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To put video in your WebView you can implement this method

```
- (void)embedYouTube {

self.videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
             <html>\
             <head>\
             <style type=\"text/css\">\
             iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
             body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
             </style>\
             </head>\
             <body>\
             <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
             </body>\
             </html>", self.videoURL];



[self.videoView loadHTMLString:self.videoHTML baseURL:nil];
}
```

To get notifications add observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(playbackDidEnd:)
name:@"MPAVControllerItemPlaybackDidEndNotification"//@"MPAVControllerPlaybackStateChangedNotification"
object:nil];
```